VBA - What could interfere with a ClearContents function?
I am trying to use the following code to clear contents of a given cell depending on which input method the user chooses (Simplified vs calculator).
Private Sub Worksheet_Changeo(ByVal ChangedCell As Range)

    Application.EnableEvents = True
    
    If Not Intersect(ChangedCell, Me.Range("B31")) Is Nothing Then
    
        If Me.Range("B31").Value = "Calculator" Then
                Range("D30:E30").Select
                Selection.ClearContents
        End If
        
    End If
    
End Sub

The code seems to work just fine when using it in a fresh workbook, so it seems that something else in my current workbook might be interfering with it (I did directly save it in the relevant sheet module btw). Does anyone have any ideas on what might be stopping the code from erasing the contents of those two cells?
Thanks,
I tried writing a code which automatically erases old iput cell contents when switching input method, it seems to work on a new workbook but not my current one and I can't tell why. There is no error message or anything.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba
No idea what might be happening but changing it to Range("D30:E30").ClearContents should be your first step.

qualify every range that it's explicitly coded to be from the specific worksheet it's meant for

Further reading: Implicit ActiveSheet reference

Worksheet_Change**o** ?  Application.EnableEvents = True at the beginning ?  Why?

Please share what should happen when the value is Simplified. At the moment nothing will happen. The comparrison If Me.Range("B31").Value = "Calculator" Then is case-sensitive i.e. A <> a. To make it case-insensitive, use If StrComp(CStr(Me.Range("B31").Value), "Calculator", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then where CStr prevents an error if the cell is an error. Remove the EnableEvents line and inside the If statement use only the following: Application.EnableEvents = False: Me.Range("D30:E30").ClearContents: Application.EnableEvents = True where each colon (:) indicates a new line.

What's with the sub signature? You mustn't change it, it is fixed: Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range) and replace ChangedCell with Target in the code. What exactly is in cell B31, a formula or a value (includes a drop-down list)? If the former, please share the formula.

@VBasic2008, In the event sub signature you cannot change the event name, ByVal and As Range. But you can omit Private or replace it by Public, and rename a variable.

A Worksheet Change: Conditionally Clear Another Range

Since you haven't answered any of my clarification questions, I'm assuming you know that the target cell has to be manually changed which includes a change via a drop-down list but excludes formulas.
Here is how the suggestions in my comments could be applied. You already know the code must be copied to the correct sheet module.
To prevent retriggering this code when clearing the range, events need to be disabled. Therefore, I additionally implemented error handling so there's no way the events remain disabled.

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Const CLEAR_RANGE_ADDRESS As String = "D30:E30"
    Const TARGET_CELL_ADDRESS As String = "B31"
    Const TARGET_VALUE As String = "Calculator"
    
    Dim tcell As Range: Set tcell = Me.Range(TARGET_CELL_ADDRESS)
    If Intersect(tcell, Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim TargetString As String: TargetString = CStr(tcell.Value)
    If StrComp(TargetString, TARGET_VALUE, vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then Exit Sub
        
    On Error GoTo ClearError
        
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    Me.Range(CLEAR_RANGE_ADDRESS).ClearContents
    
ProcExit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
ClearError:
    MsgBox "Run-time error [" & Err.Number & "]:" & vbLf & vbLf _
        & Err.Description, vbCritical
    Resume ProcExit
End Sub


Hey, thanks for the help. You were very much correct in all your assumptions. The enabling/reenabling of events is particularly helpful since the cells will get re-cleared constantly. Thanks a bunch, I would have never thought of it!.

You need to switch off the event handling and possibly put it back on afterwards, as in this example:
Private Sub Worksheet_Changeo(ByVal ChangedCell As Range)
Dim bApplication_EventsEnabled As Boolean
   
bApplication_EventsEnabled = Application.EnableEvents
Application.EnableEvents = False
    
If Not Intersect(ChangedCell, Me.Range("B31")) Is Nothing Then
    
    If Me.Range("B31").Value = "Calculator" Then
            Range("D30:E30").ClearContents
    End If
End If
    
Application.EnableEvents = bApplication_EventsEnabled
End Sub

(I also removed the "...Select, Selection.ClearContents", as more elaborated in this other post)
